# References to deterministic time complexity of language classes

Tags: time-complexity, context-free, formal-grammars

It's fairly well known that $REG \in TIME(n)$. I would like to know similar inclusions for the language classes $DCFL$ and $CFL$.

I have found a variety of claims for these classes on the internet. For instance,

- In [this diagram of the arithmetic hierarchy](http://pub.ist.ac.at/%7Emdvorak/stuff/Computational_classes.pdf), it is claimed that $DCFL \in TIME(n^2)$ and $CFL \in TIME(n^6)$.
- The Wiki article for the [Earley parser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earley_parser) claims that deterministic CFGs can be parsed in $TIME(n)$, and general context-free grammars can be parsed in $TIME(n^3)$ much like the CYK algorithm.
- Some [Stanford lecture slides I found](https://web.stanford.edu/class/archive/cs/cs103/cs103.1132/lectures/24/Small24.pdf) claim that $DCFL \in TIME(n^2)$ while $CFL \in TIME(n^{18})$(?)

I was taught that $CFL \in TIME(n^3)$ due to the fact that the CYK algorithm parses in time $O(n^3)$. Does anyone have references to the original time complexity results for these language classes?

Comment: The linked Wikipedia article on the Earley parser gives a reference to the original paper by Earley. Did you check it? Also, $\mathrm{DCFL\subseteq DTIME}(n)$ (and $\mathrm{CFL\subseteq NTIME}(n)$) is essentially trivial from the definition: a DPDA consumes each input letter in $O(1)$ time, hence it runs in $O(n)$ time in total.

Answer (score 1):

Did you read the slides in the Stanford course? A key point is that it is discussing time complexity *for a Turing Machine (TM)*. Turing Machines are only polynomially equivalent in time complexity to general computers. The precise relationship is found in the slide (in bold for convenience):  What it says is:

> #### TIME($n^{18}$)
>
> - All  CFLs  are  in  TIME($n^{18}$)
>
>   - Given  a grammar $G$, there  exists **an algorithm  on  a standard  computer** that  can decide  whether  $G$  generates  $w$  in **time  TIME(${n^3}$)**.
>   - **Since  an  $f(n)$-time  computer  program  can  be simulated  in  time  $O(f(n)^6)$  on  a TM**,  this means  all  CFLs are  in  TIME($n^{18}$)).

Of course, that's a loose bound, since it's based on a general model for converting a computer program into a TM. The graphic presents a tighter bound, but also for [DTIME](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/DTIME), which is: (again, emphasis added)

> the computational resource of computation time for a **deterministic Turing machine**.

In short, there is no contradiction here. You need to read the complexities in the context of the computational model being used. And remember that they are just upper bounds on the complexity.